# Calling SerializerMethodField('function_name') for a DateTimeField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In the Django REST API Serializer I want to call a function that would return a DateTimeField by using SerializerMethodField. It works fine for integers but returns a null for a DateTimeField

Comment: can you put the method code? I think you mean DateTime not DateTimeField because you are supposed to return a value from this method not a field.

Answer (score 0):

Could you put in your code please ?
The following example works OK:

```
test_method_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_datetime_field')

def get_datetime_field(self, obj):
    return datetime.datetime.now()
```